# Change CSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to change the `z-index` in css with javascript `#content>ul {z-index: 100;}`.

I tryed this `$('content ul').css("z-index", 49);` and other similars, but with no good result.

Comment: Are you inspecting the z-index in Firebug or the Chrome inspector?  Are you sure the value isn't changing?

Comment: The selector is wrong, use $('#content > ul') instead. or if your ul has an id="someid" use: $('#someid').css("z-index", '49');

Answer (score 3):

jQuery accepts CSS selectors just fine:

```
$('#content > ul').css("z-index", 49);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hgt9p/1/**

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$('content ul').css("z-index", "49");
```

Answer (score 1):

To change z-index, the `position` of the element needs to be other than `static`. This is the only way I can think of how you're going wrong. The other attributes the `position` property takes are: `absolute, relative, fixed`. Sorry if you already knew this, it's the only thing that I can think of which might be going wrong. Also, make sure you're including jQuery and it's working, many a time i've been fooled by an out-of-date jQuery link or for some reason it wasn't working (e.g you weren't including the jQuery Library above the jQuery script).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('content ul').css("z-index", "49");
```

should work with JQuery. However are you sure content is a tag name? I'm guessing it's a class name and you should then use
    $('.content ul').css("z-index", "49");
Use the inspector to check if the elements are getting the property.
Also the element needs to be absolute, relative or fixed for z-index to work correctly.

That said, using that Jquery selector isn't good for performance. You should look at something like

```
$('.content').find('ul').css("z-index", "49");
```

this will give you better performance. As you are now mapping directly to findElementByClassName and findElementByTagName.